# Is there a MySQL equivalent of the WITH keyword in Oracle

Tags: mysql, oracle

I am currently trying to convert some Oracle SQL to MySQL and came across the `WITH` keyword in Oracle. Is there an equivalent of `WITH` in MySQL? Thanks

`WITH` example in Oracle:

```
with cus as (select id from tb_company where id=3)
select * from cus;
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html

Comment: there didn't use to be, but now there is: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html

Comment: thanks guys, how do I accept an answer?

Comment: You can't, user99, as this was a *comment*, not an *answer* (unless @Haleemur decides to post yet another message in a form of an actual answer).

Comment: @HaleemurAli and Mat: I don't want to steal your points, but want to flag the question as answered. If you repost your comment as an answer, I will delete my version of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is an equivalent since MySQL version 8.0:

```
WITH
  cte1 AS (SELECT a, b FROM table1),
  cte2 AS (SELECT c, d FROM table2)
SELECT b, d FROM cte1 JOIN cte2
 WHERE cte1.a = cte2.c;
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html